# Building Registration Banks

Tags: keyboard

I have a PSR-S950.  I have already stored the 8 voices in the keyboard.  According to the books I should be able to store 8 additional in the next Bank #2 than another 8 voices in the next Bank #3 etc.  Problem is everytime I try to store additional voices the 1st Bank gets cancelled or the voices disappear.  How do I get the right sequence down to Save the information.

Comment: You can send a message to Yamaha asking how to do this. They will be able to answer you. https://www.yamaha.com/en/contact_us/

Comment: Here is the [user manual](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/90414.pdf). The specific steps regarding memory begin on page 79. To further answer your question, it would be necessary to know step-by-step how you're setting things up.

Answer (score 0):

- Select the voice you want to store
- Press [VOICE SETTING]
- Select "Voice Write" using the [DATA] dial
- Press [VOICE SETTING] again
- Select the bank
- Select the location (Voice 01, Voice 02,...)
- Press [YES]